# Oracle fom Nhibernate batch insert not work

Tags: oracle, nhibernate, batch-insert

```
<property name="adonet.batch_size">100</property>
```

here is some code:

```
using (var session = SessionFactory.NHSessionFactory.OpenStatelessSession())
{
  using (var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
  {
    try
    {
      foreach (var entity in entities)
      {
        session.Insert(entity);
      }
      tx.Commit();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
  }
}
```

the same code,and the same config.but oracle is not batch insert.

I try to add

```
<property name="adonet.factory_class">NHibernate.AdoNet.OracleDataClientBatchingBatcherFactory,NHibernate</property>
```

throw null object.

Answer (score 0):

Stateless sessions do not use batching.

That's it.